# Racing game in j2me(2d)

Tags: java-me

I'm developing a racing game in top-view. the roads are straight and has few curves.how to tilt the road to take a turn.

In j2me no any methods to rotate an image.  I ref and tried with 
[the following link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?206189-J2me-Image-Rotation&p=764607&viewfull=1#post764607). But in device response time very slow..

[image]

[image]

How to make this game play... Any ref or link ?

Comment: Pre-calculate the necessary rotation images.

Comment: Pre-calculation leads to out of memory exception.